# Best practice for Window Forms and SQL connection instance

Tags: c#, sql

What is best practice for C# Window Forms and SQL connection instance. I need the same SQL connection in all window forms. What is best implementation practice for this? Where do I put the SQL connection?

I am using Compact framework 3.5.

Comment: refer this [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p3.html)

Comment: It's not at all clear to me that that addresses the question at all - as well as it not being a great answer to *just* provide a link without any text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I prefer to leave connection management to the [ADO.NET connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) and everytime I want to query:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo;";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

When you call `conn.Open()` a physical connection is not opened, it is drawn from the connection pool, and when the using block end and invokes `.Dispose` the connection is not closed but returned to the connection pool in order to be reused. This improves performance and relieves me from worrying about where to put or store those SqlConnection instances in applications.

Comment: isn't that bad. To use 1000 times the same logic?

Comment: @senzacionale, that's just an example. In a real world application you will refactor this to avoid repetitions. The point of my answer was to show that you should simply use a `new SqlConnection` everytime you want to query instead of trying to store it in some static classes, fields or whatever.

Comment: +1 exactly - based on the *open as late as possible, keep it open for the shortest possible timespan, and close as soon as possible* principle

Answer (score 4):

You *say* you need the same connection in all your forms, but I don't think you should consider that to be axiomatic. You may well need to connect to the same *database* in all forms, but that's not the same thing - any more than you would need to use the same connection to make multiple requests to a web service.

I would strongly suggest three things:

- Use dependency injection to allow a single object to be provided to multiple classes/objects which all need it
- *Don't* inject the actual connection: inject something which can *provide* a connection, or perhaps just something which can execute a query for you.
- Take code which accesses the database out of the user-interface code so you can test each independently of the other.

Generally speaking, database access should be (from the caller's point of view): "open connection, do work, close connection whatever happened" (as per Darin's answer). Let .NET's connection pooling take care of the *physical* connection to the database. How you *structure* your code around that will depend on your requirements, and the extent to which they vary between forms. In many cases you may be able to get away with just asking your database access class to execute a query for you with a certain set of parameters and return the results - in other cases you may need more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 4):

As Dimitrov suggested a good approach is to open and close connections only when needed and keep it open the shortest possible time. .NET Connection pool will handle this for you so connections will be reused in a transparent way for you.

In general a good approach is to have another class library to serve as Data Access Layer which wraps the calls to database and **does not expose** any connection or command usage to the UI, so in the future you would be able to move to another database engine, if needed, changing only the DAL.

Communication from DAL and UI should consist only in objects (entities) or for simple projects DataTables and DataSets. In most of the cases a third project (class library) is in the between and it's called Business Logic, such level manipulates the data from DAL and applies your application specific business logic returning cleaner or elaborated results to the UI.

I have used this approach in many projects already, since about 11 years.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a class with the connection logic in.

Comment: what then. Use inheritence in all windows forms for this class?

Comment: It stops repeating code 1000 times like you mentioned in reply to Darin's answer.

Comment: Inherriting is one way... or you can just instantiate your connection class when you need it.

Comment: this is true but i am coding in windows forms. public partial class Main : Form

Comment: the design part?? If so, stop that :o)